# Installing Mahout with Maven on OS X Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, mahout

I am trying to play with Mahout.

Following very simple instructions on the apache website. I'm getting weird dependency errors.

I've created a new project with Maven. I've added this to the pom.xml as suggested:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
  <artifactId>mahout-mrlegacy</artifactId>
  <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

now running 'mvn clean install -U' gives me:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mrlegacy/0.9/mahout-mrlegacy-0.9.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.689 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-21T10:54:37+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.mahout:mahout-mrlegacy:jar:0.9 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Java is too hard! Seriously, I'm a Ruby guy. Now I also tried 'artifactID' as just 'mahout' as I can see that in some of these alleged maven repositories, but same error.
What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/quickstart.html) of Apache Mahout appears to have a version mix-up. `mahout-mrlegacy` does not exist in version 0.9, but [it will exist in version 0.10.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1511). For version 0.9, the dependency is actually [`mahout-core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.9).

Therefore, you should use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

When 0.10.0 will be released, you will need to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-mrlegacy</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Until the edit comes through @Tunaki is correct but the next version of Mahout will be 0.10.0. Use "mahout-core" for Mahout 0.9 and the next Mahout release is due mid-april.

Comment: @pferrel The JIRA issue [MAHOUT-1511](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1511) states that the fix version for the renaming is 1.0. Is this incorrect ?

Comment: There is no 1.0 release so there will be no published artifacts. If you are building from source you can use the version in the root pom, which may be 1.0-SNAPSHOT but the next published release will be 0.10.0 coming in mid-April. In short using 1.0 will not work.

Comment: I changed that Jira to say resolved in 0.10.0. Don't trust the resolved in fields of Jira, they are only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-mrlegacy</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.2.2.0.0-2041</version>
</dependency>
```

And below repositories

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>pentaho-releases</id>
        <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

For more details:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout/mahout-mrlegacy/0.9.0.2.2.0.0-2041

Comment: This is not a release artifact of Mahout so use at your own risk. See @Tunaki 's answer for officially supported method. Mahout 0.9 does not have an mrlegacy artifact, called core in 0.9.